# Which are good phrasal verbs for "start working on something"?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, phrasal-verbs

I would like to say something like this:

> Person 1: "We have these two tasks for you..."
>
> Person 2: "OK. I will start working on them!"

Which are good, natural and native ways of saying that?

I feel that

> OK. I will `take them in`

could be a choice, is that right?

Comment: 'Get going', 'get cracking' are verb phrases. Nobody would call them phrasal verbs; that term has enough conflicting definitions. / Are you getting confused with 'take those on'?

Comment: @Edwin, would 'take them on' be correct (for the meaning of start working on them)?

Comment: *take them on* is okay; I would probably rarely say it; and another choice is *I will tackle them*, but this is, of course, idiomatic.

Answer (score 2):

With reference to the question in the title: you can say that you'd *get started*.

> **get started** *phrase*
>   Begin a task, endeavour, or process.
>   ‘The trail features online activities to show people how to get started in exploring local history.’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/get_started)

You ask whether "take them in" works. No, that sounds more like adopting strays. :)

Answer (score 1):

"I will get on with them." (or "I'll ...")

More informally: "I'm on it."

Or, if you want to be *really* informal: "I'm all over it"!